# problem on reload tableview on tabbar project with sqlite

Tags: iphone, uitableview, tabbar

i have a project with 3 tabs, first tab have tableview with navigation, i insert data in my second tab to database, when i switch back to first tab, there is not changing,
i connect to sqlite on viewDidAppear part,and put my data in this part but there is not changing result.
thanks for help

Comment: Can you put code of storing data into sqlite and retreiving data from sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On viewDidAppear, after connecting with your database, you need to reload the table view. This will call all the table view data source functions again, such as cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I have same issue. I have also done [tableview reloadData; but it not refresh tableview. How do i fix this prob?